# In Python, loop through sheet and only count Non-NaN cells in the first column. Output name of each sheet and total found

Tags: python, pandas, nan, spreadsheet

I want to loop through each sheet, and count each non-NaN value in the first column. I want the total from each sheet, to be the name of the sheet. The header for Column A and the sheet names are unknown.

Input:

```
Column A          Sheet
Non-NaN0          sh1
Non-NaN1          sh1
Non-NaN2          sh2
```

Output:

```
sheet            total
sh1                2
sh2                1
```

Here is what I have so far, but can't seem to get it right.

```
# create data frame from workbook, skipping rows, keys are the sheet names and the values are the sheets as dataframess 
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel("C:/file/path/File.xlsx", skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,], sheet_name=None) 

# List holding sheets that have been counted
all_sheets = []

# Loop through each sheet
for SheetNameKeys, dfSheetValues in df_xlsx.items():
    dfSheetValues = dfSheetValues.iloc[:, 0] # first column as df
    dfSheetValues['SheetNames'] = SheetNameKeys # create new column and name it each sheetname filling it with sheets/keys
    dfSheetValues['TotalNonNaN'] = dfSheetValues['SheetNames'].count # add column and total non-NaN found in sheet
    all_sheets.append(dfSheetValues) # Collect totals from each sheet into list

full_table = pd.concat(all_sheets) # put all sheets together 
#full_table.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

print(full_table)
full_table.to_csv("C:/file/path/NewFile.csv", index = False)
```

I changed:

`pd.read_excel()` to include `usecols=[0]` and removed `iloc[:, 0]`

`.count` to `.value_counts()`

It gave me this output:

```
   Non-Nan SheetNames  TotalNonNaN
0  Non-Nan     Sheet1          NaN
1  Non-Nan     Sheet1          NaN
2  Non-Nan     Sheet1          NaN
3  Non-Nan     Sheet1          NaN
4      NaN     Sheet1          NaN
5      NaN     Sheet1          NaN
6      NaN     Sheet1          NaN
7  Non-Nan     Sheet1          NaN
0  Non-Nan     Sheet2          NaN
1  Non-Nan     Sheet2          NaN
2  Non-Nan     Sheet2          NaN
3      NaN     Sheet2          NaN
4  Non-Nan     Sheet2          NaN
```

I have also tried the following:

```
path = "C:/Path/file.xlsx"
main_df = pd.ExcelFile(path)
sheets = main_df.sheet_names
for sheet in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet)
    df.to_frame()
    na_count = df.isna().sum().char
    print(sheet, na_count)
```

Comment: `df['sheet'].value_counts()`?

Comment: In my data the sheet names and header of the first column are unknown.  I was attempting to use ```key: value``` in my loop to get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a list comprehension to loop through the sheets and count the sum of the not null values.  It uses this for the data of the `DataFrame`.  It then uses the keys of the workbook dictionary as the index of the `DataFrame`.  Note that I used an `OrderedDict` to ensure the the order stays consistent between the values and the index.  Note also that I left out the `skiprows` parameter to `pandas.read_excel` in order to make the code more generally reproducible, so you will likely need to add that in.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

import pandas

# Use OrderedDict to ensure that data and index have the same order
workbook = OrderedDict(pandas.read_excel('C:/file/path/File.xlsx', sheet_name=None))
result = pandas.DataFrame(
    data={
        'total': [
            df.iloc[:, 0].notnull().sum()
            for df in workbook.values()
        ]
    },
    index=pandas.Index(workbook.keys(), name='sheet'),
)
result.to_csv("C:/file/path/NewFile.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC,

```py
out = (df.loc[df['Value'].notna(), ['sheet']].value_counts()
       .to_frame('total')
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

  sheet  total
0   sh1      2
1   sh2      1
```

Comment: using this and ```df_xlsx = pd.read_excel("file")``` give the error ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually. There is no hidden temporary file

Comment: @feelsgood That seems like your `pd.read_excel` error.

Comment: The file became corrupt, amazing. I'm getting this error ```get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'Value'```

Comment: @feelsgood It seems you didn't have `Value` column, what's the result of `df.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: In my original question ```Value``` is the name of the first column I'm looping through in each sheet. I updated my quetsion to show what ```df.columns.tolist()``` gives

Comment: Looking at the first column in each sheet, the header of A-column is actually merged A-E -Does that matter?

Comment: @feelsgood If you want first column, you may try `df.iloc[:, 0]` instead of `df['Value']`.

Comment: I was using ```[:, 0]``` in my original code, added it to yours too now, to no avail. In my data the sheet names and header of the first column are unknown. I was using ```key: value``` in my loop for this reason. The sheet names become the ```key```  as well as the that name of what I'm totaling. The ```value``` are the sheets as dataframes which is where the total comes from. I add new a column ```'Sheetnames'``` which gets populated by the ```key```  and another new column ```'Totals'``` which is populated by the count of non-NaN values from the first column in ```value```

Comment: @feelsgood `df_xlsx.items()` returns column header and the column, `dfSheetValues.iloc[:, 0]` may not return the first column as you want.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of what you mean? If .items() is returning the column and header, why wouldn't .iloc give me what items() is holding?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```
import pandas as pd

path = "E:\my_file.xlsx"
main_df = pd.ExcelFile(path)
sheets = main_df.sheet_names
for sheet in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet)
    na_count = df.isna().sum().char
    print(sheet, na_count)
```

Example Output:

```
Sheet1 1
Sheet2 5
```

I'm adding .char after sum because it returns the data type too and you need the count only. Then you can write your values to a data frame immediately or by creating a dictionary and converting it to a data frame.

Comment: If I include ```sheet_name=None``` I get ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'isna'```. When I remove it, I get ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'char'```

Comment: I'm not sure the code will be clear in a comment so I'll edit my solution to add one that you can use to loop over your sheets. :)

Comment: Thank you. I attempted your solution changing only the file path and get the error ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'char'``` Here is the Traceback ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\script.py", line 30, in <module>
    na_count = df.isna().sum().char
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5583, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'char'```

Comment: This is probably because it's a series not a data frame. Could you try to add df.to_frame() in a new line before the one of na_count?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to dataframes in Python. Still getting an error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'``` I have added to my post exactly what I tried using your solution.

Comment: If you call df.isna().sum(), what do you get? Could you share the output?

Answer (score 1):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')

data = {}
for ws, name in zip(wb.worksheets, wb.sheetnames):
    data[name] = len([x for x in ws['A'][6:] if x])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but getting an error ```raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index```

Comment: You can try swapping `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` for `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, 'index')`